# admin vs. sudo user: program not working for user (sudo env problem?)

Tags: sudo, python, environment-variables

I'm working on a **QNAP NAS-system** (which alone is troublesome; firmware: 4.1.1 (not that new)) and installed **duplicity** through some community-package.

### Problem

Logged in as **admin** (which is the replacement of root within QNAPs system) through **ssh**, the following works:

```
duplicity
Command line error: Expected 2 args, got 0
Enter 'duplicity --help' for help screen.
```

Trying the same as another user fails all the time (**here: sudo -i**):

```
sudo -i -u backupScript
duplicity
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

Also **sudo --login**:

```
sudo -u backupScript --login
duplicity
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

**sudo -E** (which could be a candidate) seems not be available with my version: **1.8.14p3**.

### Debugging env-setting:

#### admin: env

```
HOSTNAME=XXX
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/sh
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.2.106 55935 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/5
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
HISTFILESIZE=1000
USER=admin
TEMP=/Apps/opt/tmp
LS_COLORS=no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:
PAGER=/bin/more
MAIL=/var/mail/admin
PATH=/Apps/opt/bin:/Apps/opt/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/ruby/bin:/Apps/bin:/Apps/sbin:/usr/local/jre/bin
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
PWD=/root
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jre
RUBY_PATH=/usr/local/ruby
EDITOR=/bin/vi
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
DMALLOC_OPTIONS=debug=0x34f47d83,inter=100,log=logfile
PS1=[\w] #
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
TERMINFO=/Apps/opt/share/terminfo
TMP=/Apps/opt/tmp
LOGNAME=admin
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.2.106 55935 192.168.2.103 22
_=/usr/bin/env
```

#### backupScript env after sudo -i -u backupScript

```
HOSTNAME=XXX
SHELL=/bin/sh
TERM=xterm
HISTSIZE=1000
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
HISTFILESIZE=1000
USER=backupScript
LS_COLORS=no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:
SUDO_USER=admin
SUDO_UID=0
USERNAME=backupScript
PAGER=/bin/more
MAIL=/var/mail/backupScript
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/ruby/bin:/Apps/bin:/Apps/sbin:/usr/local/jre/bin
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
PWD=/share/homes/backupScript
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jre
RUBY_PATH=/usr/local/ruby
EDITOR=/bin/vi
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
DMALLOC_OPTIONS=debug=0x34f47d83,inter=100,log=logfile
PS1=[\u@\h \W]\$
SHLVL=1
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/sh
HOME=/share/homes/backupScript
LOGNAME=backupScript
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
SUDO_GID=0
_=/usr/bin/env
```

- **Both doesn't have any PYTHONHOME defined (which is mentioned in the error)**
- How is admin able to run duplicity, while user backupScript is not?
- Any ideas how to repair this?
- Any ideas of further debugging-attemps? **Just mention if i'm approaching this in a completely wrong way!**

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your case the main problem is that this is missing in $PATH: `"/Apps/opt/bin:/Apps/opt/sbin"`. Probably `python` should come from there.

Actually `sudo -i` should work if user "backupScript" has the right profile/shell config files in his home `/share/homes/backupScript`. If not then change his profile or don't use --login or -i.

You could mimic `sed -E` behavior by editing `/etc/sudoers`. Either disable `Defaults env_reset` or add PATH to `Defaults env_keep`

BTW if admin is root then you don't even need to use sudo. `su` should be fine:

`su -c duplicity  backupScript`

Comment: Thanks! The ```Apps-path``` is not the reason (tried adding it) and it also does not contain Python. ```su``` is not supported on my system (and sudo needed to be installed manually too). I will have a look at your other remarks!